# Entity Reference View format

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities

Is there a way to change the Entity Reference view to a different format than an entity reference list?

I'm trying to list taxonomy terms and other custom taxonomy fields to the user when they use the edit form of the node. Ideally, I would list the taxonomy reference as a table with multiple columns. I haven't found a way to convert this list to a table. Does anyone have any idea?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Entity Reference Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module

> This module provides an advanced Entity Reference widget that uses a
>   view embedded in a modal dialog for selecting items. The view can be
>   paginated and have exposed filters.

You can also use tables in your views for referencing now.